# Preview app doesn't open since I installed MACOS Catalina

Tags: python-imaging-library, macos-catalina

```
import PIL
img = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (100,100))
img.show()
```

The error message:

> FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Preview.app) failed with error -43.

Answer (score 5):

Following from [Sean True's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880837/421225), an even quicker but temporary fix is to simply make a symbolic link to Preview.app in the old location. In the terminal run

```
ln -s /System/Applications/Preview.app /Applications/Preview.app
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: Worked great, this is the easiest fix.

Answer (score 3):

There's an official fix in github for Pillow 7, but I'm still on 6.

This appears to be a PIL ImageShow issue, with the PIL MacViewer using `/Applications/Preview.app` as an absolute path to the OSX Preview app.

It's not there in Catalina. I did a quick hack to `ImageShow.py` changing `/Applications/Preview.app` to just `Preview.app` and the issue went away. That might or might not still work on pre-Catalina OSX, but I don't have an easy way to test.

It has apparently moved to `/System/Applications/Preview.app` so a quick check at run time would probably cover both cases.

```
elif sys.platform == "darwin":

    class MacViewer(Viewer):
        format = "PNG"
        options = {'compress_level': 1}
        preview_locations = ["/System/Applications/Preview.app","/Applications/Preview.app"]
        preview_location = None
        def get_preview_application(self):
            if self.preview_location is None:
                for pl in self.preview_locations:
                    if os.path.exists(pl):
                        self.preview_location = pl
                        break
            if self.preview_location is None:
                raise RuntimeError("Can't find Preview.app in %s" % self.preview_locations)
            return self.preview_location
        def get_command(self, file, **options):
            # on darwin open returns immediately resulting in the temp
            # file removal while app is opening
            pa = self.get_preview_application()
            command = "open -a %s" % pa
            command = "(%s %s; sleep 20; rm -f %s)&" % (command, quote(file),
                                                        quote(file))
            return command

        def show_file(self, file, **options):
            """Display given file"""
            pa = self.get_preview_application()
            fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
            with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as f:
                f.write(file)
            with open(path, "r") as f:
                subprocess.Popen([
                    'im=$(cat);'
                    'open %s $im;'
                    'sleep 20;'
                    'rm -f $im' % pa
                ], shell=True, stdin=f)
            os.remove(path)
            return 1
```